# WPF: Refreshing DataGrid after columns changed in DataTable, MVVM way

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datatable, wpfdatagrid

I am using vanilla WPF `Datagrid` that has its `ItemsSource` bound to a `DataTable`:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ResultTable.DefaultView}" >
```

Where `ResultTable` is the [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx). I have tried adding rows programmatically at runtime and the `DataGrid` will update accordingly. However, the `DataGrid` does not update When I add or remove columns at runtime. Here is what I have in my ViewModel

```
class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private DataTable resultTable;
    public DataTable ResultTable
    {
        get { return resultTable; }
        set
        {
            resultTable = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ResultTable");
        }
    }

    public void AddColumn(string columnName)
    {
        ResultTable.Columns.Add(columnName);
    }
}
```

I found an almost identical question here [WPF Datagrid using MVVM.. is two way binding to DataTable possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095339/wpf-datagrid-using-mvvm-is-two-way-binding-to-datatable-possible) but there did not seem to be a conclusive answer. Unfortunately, the person who asked the question seemed to have found a workaround but did not bother to post it...

I also found a solution here http://www.mikeware.com/2012/08/datagrid-dilemma/ but it appears very "hackish" (not to mention non-MVVM) and the author himself admits that he would prefer to do it another way if he found one.

How can I force the `DataGrid` to update when I add new columns? I prefer to do it in a MVVM way if possible.

Comment: Have you tried re-setting the whole `ResultTable` object in your view model? Otherwise your view will not be notified. Your case is a little bit special because not only the data changes, but also the structure of the data changes (the columns).

Comment: @Martin, I tried raising the `PropertyChangedEventHandler` in the `set` of `ResultTable`. Then I forced a refresh by setting `ResultTable = null` and back to the original referecence. Unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: Take a look at this: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755838/how-to-programmatically-add-columns-to-wpf-datagrid-with-mvvm`

Comment: @Martin, Turns out you were right, I was simply not reseting the ResultTable in the correct way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First add this code to ViewModel:

```
private static readonly DataTable _dt = new DataTable();
```

Then you can add that what like this code when you add column:

```
public void AddColumn(string columnName)
{
    var temp = this.ResultTable;
    this.ResultTable = _dt;
    temp.Columns.Add(columnName);
    this.ResultTable = temp;
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and it did not work, can you explain this answer a bit more?

Comment: Can you show me the property `ResultTable` how do you declared? My code just tried to trigger the `OnPropertyChanged`, so the `DataGrid` will be refresh. Set `ResultTable = null` maybe can not trigger it.

Comment: I just added more detail to my question. ObservableObject is a class I created that implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: My bad, this actually works! I made a mistake, I was setting the private member `resultTable` instead of setting the property `ResultTable`. In fact, setting the property to `null` also works!

Comment: @DaveS That's great! I'm happy to help you!